# How to use the iterator tag in Struts2?

Tags: select, struts2, tags

I have

```
class A {
   private String field1;
   private String field2;
   private B b;
}

class B {
   private String field3;
}

List<A> myList;
```

How can I access the field3 using the myList?

This would work for field1 and field2, but how about field3?

```
 <s:iterator value="myList">
                <tr>
                    <td><s:property value="field1"/></td>
                    <td><s:property value="field2"/></td>

                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

Comment: What has this to do with the "select tag" ?? Did you mean "iterator tag"?
BTW, I hope your classes A B have the corresponding getters

Comment: +2 for getters. They have to have get(if not set) methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's:

```
b.field3
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be b.field3